# Notepad++ won't filter filenames with wildcards on File > Open

Tags: notepad++

Choosing File > Open or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> in Notepad++ presents the list of files in the current folder, but I can't filter with wildcards, like *.txt. When I do that and click Open the Open dialog just disappears. Any way to fix this?

I'm also seeing a problem with File > Save As... when I enter .. in the filename field it says "That file already exists, overwrite?"

Comment: Try reinstalling notepad++

Comment: @slugger4145 
    goto Settings->Preferences->Default Directory and check use new style dialog…
via 
https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/15480/using-wildcards-to-filter-files-in-the-open-dialog 
via 
googling: notepad++ wildcard doesn't filter directory

Comment: that was it, thank you! @user26398

Comment: @user26398 - thank you. I would vote if you posted your answer (this was bugging me for months!)

Comment: @danielwilliams So let it be written; so let it be done. I'm glad it helped. Peace.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Settings > Preferences > Default Directory` and check use new style dialog

via [notepad++ community: Using wildcards to filter files in the Open dialog](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/15480/using-wildcards-to-filter-files-in-the-open-dialog?_=1612839671682&lang=en-US)

via googling: notepad++ wildcard doesn't filter directory